# How to send form data that is made by mobile jquery to a php file to store in mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

please friend help me.
I make a form using mobile jquery and I want to send it's information to a php file that is hosted in local host when I fill the form when I press the submit button a dialog box appears that says " Error Page Loading "
I don't know what to do with this
[It is the code of the form that must send the users information

[It is the code of php file that must process the users data and send it to the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmPAr.jpg)

Comment: Show your code and try to learn about form tag

Comment: You should copy and paste your code into your question

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's get or post to send the data to php and make sure the name of the page your sending it to must be included as an argument to the method

Comment: I have chosen not to recommend this answer for deletion in the review queue - but please elaborate on your answer, preferably providing an example of the code required.